# Java String pool Storage doubts

Tags: java, string, jvm, hashcode

why hashcode are same of string object ???

I'm trying to understand how string pool works.I have gone through many sites and finally i'm more confused now. Let me put down my doubts here. Someone help me in understanding them.

```
class cov {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abc"; //Object on string pool  
        System.out.println(s.hashCode());
        String str = new String("abc"); //This statement does two things  
        System.out.println(str.hashCode());


    }
}
```

Comment: The question that this has been marked as a duplicate of is a completely different question!  Did anyone bother to check before closing this?  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

A String's `hashCode()` method is calculated based on the chars it contains. If two String objects contain the *same* chars with the same case and in the same order, then they will have the same `hashCode()`.

Comment: but one is stored on the string constant pool and other on the heap ?

Comment: @user2723924: the `hashCode()` method depends ***only*** on the state of the object, and for Strings that means the contents. Period.

Comment: @user2723924 all objects in java are on the heap.

Comment: @user2723924 that doesn't change the fact how String's hashcode will be calculated. if you are really eager to check their diff hascode then try `System.identityHashCode(str)`

Comment: @ Brian Roach, String s = "Java"; it will not be in heap ??

Comment: @user2723924: your point being?

Comment: @user2723924: every object is on the heap. Period.

Comment: @user2723924 I'm not sure what part of **all objects in java are on the heap** was unclear, or what it is you're asking.

Comment: I swear I'm going to write a blog post titled "there's nothing special about strings in java".

Comment: @BrianRoach: .... except for 1) the pool, 2) some operator overloading, and 3) it may be the first immutable class that newbies come in contact with.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels none of which, with the exception of the concat operator, are *special*. There are plenty of implementations of the flyweight pattern in the world. Aside of that.. Its still a plain old object on the heap.

Comment: @BrianRoach: I don't disagree with you, but you have to admit that it's often the first and major experience of us mere mortals with the flyweight pattern and with immutable objects. That in and of itself makes the class special.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think we're violently agreeing with each other, but my point is that if you treat a `String` like any other object in java, there's no surprises. The confusion seems to come from people thinking it's *special* because of the things you mention.

Comment: @BrianRoach: Agree. Violently. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `String` class has a `hashCode` method that calculates the hash code from its content, not from its memory location.  So if two strings are identical (but not necessarily equal), they will have the same hash code.

If this were not the case, a structure such as `HashSet<String>` would be unusable - every new `String` would turn out not to be in the set, even when a `String` with the same characters had already been added.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the source code which is used for generating hashCode

```
public int hashCode() {
int h = hash;
if (h == 0) {
    int off = offset;
    char val[] = value;
    int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

And as described in other answers hashCode is generated from the contents of the String not the place where it is residing. e.g heap stack or constant pool